# How to block app from using specific hotkey

Tags: windows-10, administrator, hotkeys

I have two different Windows programs that I need to use simultaneously which both rely on the ALT+H hotkey. Whenever I press it, it executes that hotkey in both of these applications even if I do not have the window selected.

One of them is the freeware SimpleStickyNotes. No matter whether I have the app open or I have another app open, if I press ALT+H, then SimpleStickyNotes will get minimized. I want to prevent this specific behaviour. There's no option inside the software.

How can I "block"/prevent one of the apps from using this hotkey, assuming there is no setting inside the app to do so? Is there some administrator/command line trick I can do?

Comment: Comments from a now deleted answer: what app? One of them is the freeware SimpleStickyNotes. No matter whether I have the app open or I have another app open, if I press ALT+H, then SimpleStickyNotes will get minimized. I want to prevent this specific behaviour. There's no option inside the software, I'm hoping for some hack/command line thing I can do to block that hotkey from working (if that makes sense)